# "Redimir" descuentos

Tags: significado

Quidiera confirmar si "redimir" en "[redimir Descuentos Cortefiel para pagar la compra de productos que se encuentren a la venta en nuestras Tiendas del país donde el Socio se dio de alta](https://clubcortefiel.cortefiel.com/es/es/condiciones-generales/#:%7E:text=Los%20Cheques%20se%20emitir%C3%A1n%20siempre,la%20fecha%20de%20su%20emisi%C3%B3n.)" significa "canjear" ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redimir no significa "canjear", aunque se usa con ese significado por una mala traducción de *redeem*, en inglés.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su explicación! Y perdone por no haber podido responder antes ~